# Accessing Windows dialog boxes from Selenium and java

Tags: java, selenium

I am testing web site functionality with Selenium using Java from Eclipse.  One test is to click a "download" button, look for a popup window (this is another selenium window), respond to that window which should then cause a Windows download dialog to pop up (please see attached image).

Please note.  I do not have to actually download the file.  Just verify that the windows dialog popped up.

I know from experience (or at least am unaware) that Selenium can actually access the Windows download box, choose a file location and start the download.  But all I need to do is verify that the download box popped up.  Exiting the chromedriver will kill the download window so it won't linger but I still need to verify it was created.

Any suggestions?  One thing I tried was having the task manager open.  I thought I could find a process corresponding to the dialog box, but there were 119 processes before the dialog box came up as well as when it was up.  So any suggestions what to do?

I could add as an aside that someone wrote a workaround to actually download the file.  Instead of clicking on a button or link he pretended to be the Windows dialog box and accepted the download.  That, for reasons I stated above, will not work in this instance as I have to verify the actual results of clicking the button.

Please see my attached image for an example of the dialog box.[image]

Comment: Please show you code that you were trying on?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?  I don't have code right now.  Trying to figure out how to do it.  Before I write any automation I always test it out manually first.  That is as far as I have gotten.  When I mentioned having the task manager open it was when I was manually performing the test ;-)

Comment: Only way to handle Window dialog boxes are Using AutoIT or Robot class.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround to meet this test requirement is, once you responds to the window which results in a Windows download dialog, try performing the next action. This will result in a **WebDriverException** as the access to UI will be blocked by the Windows dialog. You can then catch this **WebDriverException** and in the catch block press escape key using **Robot** class in Java. Following is an example:

```
try {
    //1) Respond to the window that results in Windows dialog box.
    //2) Perform the next action on UI. 
} catch (WebDriverException we) {
    //3) You can capture screen shot as well at this stage.
    System.out.println("Most likely Windows dialog appeared.");
    //4) Press escape key using Robot class in Java
    Robot r = new Robot();
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
}
```

Comment: I will try that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutoIT to check if the windows dialog appears, then save the status of the windows dialog in somewhere(eg. a temp file), then you read the status of the windows dialog using Java from Eclipse

Comment: I know we used Auto IT before for something but it was frowned upon.  I think it may not work from Jenkins.  They were also looking into Test Complete but I do not know how that works.